# typescript tsconfig allows .json import, built files (.js) do not. What gives?

Tags: json, typescript, es6-modules

after adding `"resolveJsonModule": true` to my project .tsconfig, I am able to directly import data from `.json` files. Project runs okay, even with nodemon.

But when then project is built, and all the files are compiled to a `dist` folder, running `node dist/index.js` now fails when it encounters the json import. The actual build command appears to be:

```
babel src --out-dir dist --extensions .js,.ts --source-maps
```

This is a server-side, non-webpack project.

tsconfig as requested:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": ["./types"],
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true ,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node", 
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true 
  }
}
```

Comment: if you can also share ts config and error details?

Comment: @Supercool. added tsconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems json files are being compiled too.Try excluding them

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {...},
  "exclude": [
    "foldercontainingjsonfiles/*.json"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This worked locally... wanted to wait to see if it worked in remote environment... It works gr8 - thanks!! :D I did not know about this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Check that dist folder structure doesn't change after .json import. I had a similar problem when I imported a `config.json` which was outside `src` folder with `*.ts` files. Moving .json files inside `src` folder fixed the issue.